# How to create a Page View Controller like Instagram homepage that also scrolls Tab Bar?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbar, uipageviewcontroller, swift4.2

I want to create a home page like Instagram, that scrolls vertically (with a Navigation Controller, Tab Bar Items, ...) to another View Controller. For example when I swipe left from Instagram home page, it will scroll to direct messages with another Tab Bar Item and the Tab Bar also moves left and is replaced with a new Tab Bar in direct messages View Controller.

[image]

I tried to use UIPageViewController but because I use a Tab Bar, when I start scrolling, the Tab Bar remains in its place. How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that the Tab Bar remains in place even when swiping horizontally, I believe your View Controller hierarchy looks something like this:

```
UITabBarController
└── UIPageViewController
    ├── UIViewController1
    ├── UIViewController2
    ├── .
    ├── .
    ├── .
```

But you need to put Tab Bar Controller inside the Page View Controller, so your View Controller hierarchy would become like this:

```
UIPageViewController
└── UITabBarController
    ├── UIViewController1
    ├── UIViewController2
    ├── .
    ├── .
    ├── .
```

Comment: thank you Behdad. This worked for me. But now the problem is when the user goes to `Tabbar` children, all children have swipe gesture and can see `UITabBarController` siblings. i do this but i think there is better way: by default `scrollView` in `UIPageViewController` has `isScrollEnabled = false`. just in `viewWillAppear` in `UIViewController1` i set this true

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `UIPageViewController` as before, and having each of your pages be a `UITabViewController` with your views being nested in the tabviewcontroller.